crons started executing only post uncommenting lines in /etc/pam.d/common-auth
My crons were not getting executed on my Ubuntu 20.04 server until I found out that these lines needed to be uncommented in /etc/pam.d/common-auth
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so

# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
# end of pam-auth-update config

Why was this so ? I don't recollect doing this previously. Did something get changed ?

From your question  I don't recollect doing this previously. What does this mean or refer too?

I have setup crons before - crontab -e worked just fine. I don't recollect editing this common-auth file.
